# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Subquery returns more than 1 row on all rows where emailAccess is thesame

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, hql

I am trying to retrieve all rows where emailAccess is equal to john@yahoo.com

**user table is structured this way**

```
id | name | email         | emailAccess
1  | john |john@yahoo.com | john@yahoo.com
2  | jeff |jeff@yahoo.com | john@yahoo.com
```

**I have a log table like this**

```
id | userId | message 
1  | 1      | bla bla
2  | 2      | 1234
```

now I am using the following hql query to retrieve the log based on the userId where emailAccesss from sesssion is **john@yahoo.com**

```
String hql = "FROM Chat c WHERE c.user = (FROM User u WHERE u.emailAccess = :emailAccess)";

        return  _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql).setParameter("emailAccess", emailAccess).list();
```

trying to use the above hql query gives me this error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
```

**second stacktrace**

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Subquery returns more than 1 row
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
```

Where am I failing.
Kindly assist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using hql allows you to access objects and their attributes, try this query :

```
String hql = "FROM Chat c WHERE c.user.emailAccess = :emailAccess"
```

Comment: the display is not sorted according to the rows

Comment: `FROM Chat c WHERE c.user.emailAccess = :emailAccess order by c.id`

Answer (score 1):

```
(FROM User u WHERE u.emailAccess = :emailAccess)
```

This returns more than one row and you have:

```
WHERE c.user =
```

You can't have an equals with multiple results on the right.  Either change your query to return a single row or change to be something like:

```
WHERE c.user in
```